# Index a shared folder with Solr

Tags: solr, shared-directory

How can I index a shared folder (not local) with Solr ? Is it possible or should I copy my shared folder into a local folder ?

Comment: @UweAllner I don't really know the name in english, currently I index files with 'java -classpath C:\solr-7.3.1\dist\solr-core-7.3.1.jar -Dauto=yes -Dc=core-Ddata=files -Drecursive=yes org.apache.solr.util.SimplePostTool C:\path\Documents\Test\*' and "Test" is on my computer but I want to do the same thing with a folder on an other computer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can definitely run the indexer on the different server from Solr. You just need to run [the post tool](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/7_3/post-tool.html#simpleposttool) with the right parameters.

So, two things:

- You can run the post tool as a jar, not as a classpath and full name invocation
- You can see all supported parameters by running: java -jar example\exampledocs\post.jar **-h**  , the one you want is **-Durl**

Comment: I d'ont understand because the path of my files is not an URL. The path for the files I want to index is something like that '\\folder\document$' and for this folder there is a login and a password

Comment: Ok, that's a bit of a different question and is more Windows issue than Solr. I think if you map the shared folder to a letter in Windows, it will allow you to provide login/password then. This way Solr does not need to know it is shared.